# Datadog: Is it possible to create templates to apply to many hosts?

Tags: monitoring

When we have many hosts running the same services or the same role, is there a way in Datadog to apply a template to these hosts so that they get automatically populated with alerts ?

And i could also modify the template and it would update on all hosts ?

Or maybe there is another way to achieve that in Datadog ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Datadog agent replied to my question on their KB page: http://help.datadoghq.com/customer/portal/questions/4978080-is-it-possible-to-create-templates-to-apply-to-many-hosts-

> Alexis Lê-Quôc
>   DEC 30, 2013 06:58AM EST
>   Datadog Agent
>   You can indeed do that with “Multi-alerts”, basically creating one alert that’s going to apply to all the hosts that share the same tags. Here’s a more detailed guide to alerting: http://docs.datadoghq.com/guides/alerting/